# Select2 drop down list has -5px offset left relative to display value of select2. Can't change with jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I'm using `bootstrap`, `jquery ui`, `select2`, etc. in one page. This has caused the `select2` drop down list to have a `-5px` offset to the left relative to the display value (after selection) of the `select2`.

I have tried to move the drop down list right with the following code:

```
   var select2_pos = $("html body span.select2-container.select2-container--default.select2-container--open").position();
   select2_pos.left = select2_pos.left + 5;
   $("html body span.select2-container.select2-container--default.select2-container--open").position(select2_pos);
```

But this gives me the error:

```
TypeError: select2_pos is null
```

Does anyone know how I can accomplish this?

Comment: Did you used $(document).ready() ? It's look like jQuery lib is not laded

Comment: I did. It is loaded. It's an old version `(1.7.1)` though due to it coming with `OpenJSGrid2.1.7`.

Comment: Ok first thing: You cannot set new "left" position by using .position(). According to https://api.jquery.com/position/ this function can only get position of element. You can use something like $(elemen).css("left", select2_pos.left + "px") (or ".css("margin-left", ...) if it's positioning relative.

Comment: Thanks, but it's throwing the error on the `select2_pos.left = select2_pos.left + 5;`

Comment: Looks like `jquery position` does not work with hidden elements, and I assume the drop down list would be hidden initially. Not sure if there is another way to get the position or how to set it when it gets revealed.

Comment: So maybe you have wrong selector? Check it by that code (if it's return 0 - you have wrong selector, and if return more than 1, you need to specify your element more clearly): $("html body span.select2-container.select2-container--default.select2-container--open").length

Comment: I used Firefox copy css path, so it should be right.

Comment: Without code i can't find what's causing problem. My last guess is that maybe there's some library conflict: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12611983/typeerror-is-null/18470043

Comment: I changed `$(document).ready(function(){` to `jQuery(function($){` as suggested in your link, but I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: I meant the noConflict answer exactly: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12612133/4551487

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The wrong position of the dropdown occurs the first time you click the dropdown and the first time you click the dropdown after a search that has no results.

[Here is a workaround](https://github.com/select2/select2-bootstrap-theme/issues/41#issuecomment-310825598) that seems to work for many people (including me). My implementation below:

```html
<select class="form-control" data-use-select2="true" name="assessment[assigned_to_id]" id="assessment_assigned_to_id">
<option value="">Select User...</option>
<option value="12">org0user0@test.com</option>
<option value="11">org0user1@test.com</option>
</select>
<select class="form-control" data-use-select2="true" name="assessment[approver_id]" id="assessment_approver_id" >
<option value="">Select User...</option>
<option value="12">org0user0@test.com</option>
<option value="11">org0user1@test.com</option>
</select>
```

```
    // data-select2 conflicts with library code. data-something-select2 works
    // set the dropdownParent to fix positioning error
    // https://github.com/select2/select2-bootstrap-theme/issues/41#issuecomment-310825598
    $("select[data-use-select2]").each(function() {
        $(this).select2({
            theme: "bootstrap4",
            dropdownParent: $(this).parent()
        });
    });
```